# Calculation inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of objects like this

```
let items = [
    {
        key: 1,
        name: 'abc',
        quanitity: 2,
        rate: 10
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        name: 'abc 12',
        quanitity: 4,
        rate: 14
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        name: 'abc',
        quanitity: 12,
        rate: 12
    } ]
```

now what I am doing is making a cart, now I want to display the total sum at the bottom based on the array.
like this will return `2 * 10 + 4 * 14 + 12 * 12 = totalAmount`.

this is what I tried using forEach

```
let dd = p.forEach((x) => {
        let totalAmount = 0;

      if (totalAmount === 0) {
        let cal = Number(x.quantity) * Number(x.rate);
        totalAmount = totalAmount + cal;
      } else {
        let cal2 = Number(x.quantity) * Number(x.rate);
        totalAmount = cal2;
      }
      console.log("cal  sdda", totalAmount);

      return totalAmount;
    });
```

I used `forEach` but I am not getting the desired output, as well as used `reduce` but I know that won't work.
Any help

Comment: Please _show us_ what you tried.

Comment: why reduce won't work?? ,did you try anything

Comment: Just do reduce: https://jsfiddle.net/fLptve71/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const items = [
  { key: 1, name: 'abc', quanitity: "2", rate: "10" },
  { key: 2, name: 'abc 12', quanitity: "4", rate: "14" },
  { key: 3, name: 'abc', quanitity: "12", rate: "12" }
];

const totalAmount = items.reduce((total, { quanitity=0, rate=0 }) =>
  total + (+quanitity * +rate)
, 0);

console.log(totalAmount);
```

Using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const items = [
  { key: 1, name: 'abc', quanitity: "2", rate: "10" },
  { key: 2, name: 'abc 12', quanitity: "4", rate: "14" },
  { key: 3, name: 'abc', quanitity: "12", rate: "12" }
];

let totalAmount = 0;
items.forEach(({ quanitity=0, rate=0 }) =>
  totalAmount += (+quanitity * +rate)
);

console.log(totalAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this

**Update:**

You can use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or `+` to convert from `string` to `number`.

```js
let items = [{key: 1,name: 'abc',quanitity: "2",rate: "10"},
              { key: 2, name: 'abc 12', quanitity: "4", rate: "14"},
              { key: 3, name: 'abc', quanitity: "12", rate: "12" }];
    
const result = items.reduce((totalAmount, {quanitity, rate}) => totalAmount + (Number(quanitity) * Number(rate)), 0);

console.log(result);
```

**Solution 2: Using `forEach`**

```js
let items = [{key: 1,name: 'abc',quanitity: "2",rate: "10"},
              { key: 2, name: 'abc 12', quanitity: "4", rate: "14"},
              { key: 3, name: 'abc', quanitity: "12", rate: "12" }];
    
let totalAmount = 0;
items.forEach(item => totalAmount += Number(item.quanitity) * Number(item.rate));
console.log(totalAmount);
```

Comment: this is what i need but the thing is that the quantity and the rate are in string format.
now i added Number like this but still getting NaN
const result = p.reduce((acc, { quanitity, rate }) => {
      acc += Number(quanitity) * Number(rate);

      return acc;
    }, 0);

Comment: I've updated my answer. you should remove `{` in your code @RishavSinha

Comment: const totalAmount = items.reduce((prev: any, curr: any) =>  prev + (+curr.quanitity * +curr.rate || 0) ,0);
console.log(totalAmount);

Comment: @Rishav Sinha Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help :)

Comment: @Phong Thanks a lot exactly what i need.I really get confused with reduce.
i can work with other methods but reduce is really hard to get.
anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: @RishavSinha Ok, I've just update `Solution 2: Using forEach`, Pls take a look at